# Return rows in a UNION query that haven't been returned already

Tags: sql, sql-server

Firstly, apologies, as this is a lot of code and tables, but believe it or not, this really is the most Minimally Reproducible Example I could make whilst being able to accurately explain it clearly.

**EDIT:** For context - this dataset will be bound to a front-end continuous form that needs to have the data in this format so it can be an 'updateable' recordset and the scheduler user can toggle each day "on/off". Having it as a single field with a date/day column will mean this can't be achieved (on first glance).

I have a data table that shows a list of all Employees and their availability for Monday - Sunday as a boolean value and the number of days since they last worked a day as an integer:

```
+-------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------+
| EmpID |   Name    | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | LastDay |
+-------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------+
|     1 | Paul      |   1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |      11 |
|     2 | Rob       |   1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |      19 |
|     3 | Christine |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |      15 |
|     4 | Annie     |   0 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   0 |      14 |
|     5 | Billie    |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   1 |       4 |
|     6 | Ben       |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |       1 |
|     7 | Lacey     |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |     110 |
|     8 | Satia     |   1 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   1 |      25 |
|     9 | Derek     |   0 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   0 |      29 |
|    10 | Larry     |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   1 |      11 |
|    11 | Matt      |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |      22 |
|    12 | Steven    |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |      14 |
|    13 | Ellie     |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |      17 |
|    14 | Amy       |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |      16 |
+-------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------+
```

The users need to be scheduled in a similar format for a working week, and to do this, I want a query that will extract the `TOP 2` users who are eligible to work, based on whoever worked the longest ago for fairness.

The expected output is in this format:

```
+-------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| EmpID |   Name    | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri |
+-------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     2 | Rob       |   1 |     |     |     |     |
|     1 | Paul      |   1 |     |     |     |     |
|     3 | Christine |     |   1 |     |     |     |
|     4 | Annie     |     |   1 |     |     |     |
|     5 | Billie    |     |     |   1 |     |     |
|     6 | Ben       |     |     |   1 |     |     |
|     9 | Derek     |     |     |     |   1 |     |
|    11 | Matt      |     |     |     |   1 |     |
|     8 | Satia     |     |     |     |     |   1 |
|    10 | Larry     |     |     |     |     |   1 |
+-------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

This has essentially taken the next two eligible users for Monday, put them in descending order of who has worked most recently, and then moves onto Tuesday. This is where the issue for me lies, because when I extract the next TOP 2 users, it will pick Paul again, as he has worked most recently. But as he has already been picked for Monday, I want it to exclude him now.

I have found a few entirely inefficient ways of doing this, including one way that actually maxed out SSMS' resources, and found that what I am doing now is essentially, a `UNION` query for each day, and each new `UNION` has to check the previous `UNION` queries to check if they have already been selected, and this is getting incredibly complex and inefficient:

```
-- MONDAY
SELECT *
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP 8
           a.EmpID,
           a.Name,
           1 as [Mon],
           0 as [Tue],
           0 as [Wed],
           0 as [Thu],
           0 as [Fri]
      FROM availability AS a
     WHERE 1=1
           AND a.MonAvailable = 1
     ORDER BY LastDay
  ) as Monday

 UNION ALL

-- TUESDAY
SELECT *
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP 8
           a.EmpID,
           a.Name,
           0 as [Mon],
           1 as [Tue],
           0 as [Wed],
           0 as [Thu],
           0 as [Fri]
      FROM availability AS a
     WHERE 1=1
           AND a.TueAvailable = 1
           AND a.EmpID NOT IN
           (
              SELECT a.EmpID
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT TOP 8
                        a.EmpID
                    FROM availability AS a
                    WHERE 1=1
                        AND a.MonAvailable = 1
                    ORDER BY LastDay
                ) as Monday
           )
     ORDER BY LastDay
  ) as Tuesday

  UNION ALL

  -- WEDNESDAY
  SELECT *
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP 8
           a.EmpID,
           a.Name,
           0 as [Mon],
           0 as [Tue],
           1 as [Wed],
           0 as [Thu],
           0 as [Fri]
      FROM availability AS a
     WHERE 1=1
           AND a.WedAvailable = 1
           AND a.EmpID NOT IN
           (
              SELECT EmpID
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT TOP 8
                        EmpID
                    FROM availability
                    WHERE 1=1
                        AND MonAvailable = 1
                    ORDER BY LastDay
                ) as Monday

               UNION ALL

              SELECT EmpID
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT TOP 8
                        EmpID
                    FROM availability
                    WHERE 1=1
                        AND TueAvailable = 1
                    ORDER BY LastDay
                ) as Tuesday
           )
     ORDER BY LastDay
  ) as Wednesday
```

Obviously this is resource heavy, incredibly ineffecient and borderline painful. What is the best way of doing this; what am I doing so wrong here?

Comment: At first glance, what I think you're doing wrong here is to store each day of the week (a date) in a separate column.  This is probably the source of the SQL acrobatics you have to do write your query.  Consider redesigning your table so that it has just a single date column.

Comment: I totally agree with @Tim BIegeleisen. Having each day as different column is 'repeated groups', a violation of the first Normal Form. Your queries will be much easier if you change your table to only have one column named "day" instead. Actually, even if you don't, the calculations are so ugly that you should rather unpivot, make your queries, and pivot back.

Comment: I also fully agree with you @TimBiegeleisen - and it originally was setup a single boolean column and a date/day. The issue with that, is it's going to be bound to a front-end form that will need the data displayed in this format so that someone 'scheduling' the week, can toggle days on and off. If it's in another format, or a pivot, it will not be an 'updateable' record when it's grouped etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clunky, however, i think you could try the code below. It's using CTE's to store the working list of empid's. Would be better to perhaps add and store these in a temp table as you work through the data.

```
with availability (empid,name,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,lastday) as 
(
select empid,name,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,lastday from availability
)
, monday (norder,empid,name,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,lastday) as 
(select top 2 1,empid,name,mon,0,0,0,0,lastday from availability where mon=1 order by lastday desc)
,   list1 as (select * from monday)
, tuesday (norder,empid,name,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,lastday) as 
(select top 2 2,empid,name,0,tue,0,0,0,lastday from availability where tue=1 and empid not in (select empid from list1) order by lastday desc)
,   list2 as (select * from monday union select * from tuesday)
, wednesday (norder,empid,name,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,lastday) as 
(select top 2 3,empid,name,0,0,wed,0,0,lastday from availability where wed=1 and empid not in (select empid from list2) order by lastday desc)
,   list3 as (select * from monday union select * from tuesday union select * from wednesday)
, thursday (norder,empid,name,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,lastday) as 
(select top 2 4,empid,name,0,0,0,thu,0,lastday from availability where thu=1 and empid not in (select empid from list3) order by lastday desc)
,   list4 as (select * from monday union select * from tuesday union select * from wednesday union select * from thursday)
, friday (norder,empid,name,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,lastday) as 
(select top 2 5,empid,name,0,0,0,0,fri,lastday from availability where fri=1 and empid not in (select empid from list4) order by lastday desc)
,   list5 as (select * from monday union select * from tuesday union select * from wednesday union select * from thursday union select * from friday)
select * from list5 order by norder asc, lastday desc
```